# How to pass items to a function to set categories?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am building a function to sort a number of automated messages received daily in a shared email inbox. I use a loop to go through each mail message in the inbox and an IF statement to filter/sort messages and then run this function:

```
Function MoveSort(olDestination As Outlook.Folder)
    Dim StCategory
    If oItems.Item(i).Categories = "" Then
        oItems.Item(i).Categories = "Category"
    End If

    oItems.Item(i).UnRead = False
    oItems.Item(i).Save
    oItems.Item(i).Move olDestination
End Function
```

The Category is usually not getting assigned. (Sometimes it will seemingly randomly assign it to the first or last message.)

This is the main procedure:

```
Private i As Integer
Private oItems As Outlook.Items

Sub OrganizeIt()
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim oInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oBStock As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oCStock As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oStock As Outlook.Folder
    Dim SEmail As String
    Dim SSubject As String

    Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oInbox = oNS.folders("HelpDeskEmail").folders("Inbox")
    Set oItems = oInbox.Items
    Set oCStock = oInbox.folders("Folder1")
    Set oBStock = oInbox.folders("Folder2")

    For i = oItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        SEmail = oItems.Item(i).SenderEmailAddress
        SSubject = oItems.Item(i).Subject
        If SEmail = "Email1@email.com" Or SSubject = "Sample Subject 1" Or _
            Left(SSubject, 16) = "Sample Subject 2" Then
            
            MoveSort oStock

        ElseIf SEmail = "Email2@email.com" Then

            MoveSort oBStock

        ElseIf SEmail = "Email3@email.com" Then

            MoveSort oCStock
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't appear to be looping through your items. Where is your definition and assignment of variables i and oItems? Also, why are you using a function if you are not returning any value?

Comment: This is the function I am calling from my main procedure within the loop. It fires whenever the loop in the main function finds an email that fits within the designated criteria. The variables are all defined (oItems is a Private variable.) I'll put the main procedure up here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is multiple dot notation taken to its extreme - the following code sets Unread property on one object and calls Save on a completely different object that has no idea about anything else your code has previously done.

```
oItems.Item(i).UnRead = False
oItems.Item(i).Save
```

Do not use multiple dot notation and do not make i a global variable - pass the object as a parameter

```
Function MoveSort(olDestination As Outlook.Folder, Item as Object)
Dim StCategory
If Item.Categories = "" Then
    Item.Categories = "Category"
End If

Item.UnRead = False
Item.Save
Item.Move olDestination
End Function

...
Dim Item as Object
For i = oItems.Count To 1 Step -1
    set Item = oItems.Item(i)
    SEmail = Item.SenderEmailAddress
    SSubject = Item.Subject
    If SEmail = "Email1@email..com" Or SSubject = "Sample Subject 1" Or _
        Left(SSubject, 16) = "Sample Subject 2" Then

        MoveSort oStock, Item

    ElseIf SEmail = "Email2@email.com" Then

        MoveSort oBStock, Item

    ElseIf SEmail = "Email3@email.com" Then

        MoveSort oCStock, Item
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Works great, I'm self-taught and mostly use vb for Excel. Just for future reference, if you do not store the referenced item as a single object, each line is instead read as a separate object?

Comment: Do you mean if you keep calling "oItems.Item(i)"? Yes, you will get a brand new COM object each time even though it happens to refer to the same Outlook message. But since the messages are transacted (MailItem.Save is required), the changes will never be saved in case of multiple dot notation.